# How to read all files in the directory and store them in the pointer in the C language program?

Tags: c, pointers, readfile, readdir

```
Mingw x86_64 v11.2.0
Windows 10 21H2
```

My current problem is that this function can normally read files and folders in the directory, but if it is saved in the pointer and printed on the screen, a single file will appear repeatedly.

These are the files in the directory.

```
.
..
main.c
main.exe
README.md
test.txt
```

The following is the source code I wrote:

```c
#include "../DeleteCompletely.h"
#include <dirent.h>

#define TotalNumber      4096
#define TotalFileNameLen 4096

typedef struct dirent DIRENT;

typedef struct {
    DIR    *dir_ptr;
    DIRENT *dirent_ptr;
    char  **pathSet;
    size_t  number;
} snDIR;

static snDIR *getAllFile(const char *path)
{
    snDIR *dirSet = (snDIR *)malloc(sizeof(snDIR));
    dirSet->dir_ptr = opendir(path);
    size_t loopIndex;

    dirSet->pathSet = (char **)malloc(sizeof(char **) * TotalNumber);
    if(dirSet->dir_ptr) {
        dirSet->number = 0;
        loopIndex = 0;
        while ((dirSet->dirent_ptr = readdir(dirSet->dir_ptr)) != NULL) {
            dirSet->pathSet[loopIndex] = (char *)malloc(TotalFileNameLen);
            dirSet->pathSet[loopIndex] = dirSet->dirent_ptr->d_name;

            dirSet->number++;
            loopIndex++;
        }
        closedir(dirSet->dir_ptr);
    }

    return dirSet;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    snDIR *set = getAllFile(".");

    for(size_t x = 0; x < set->number; ++x) {
        printf("%s\n", set->pathSet[x]);
    }

    free(set);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: DeleteCompletely.h
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

Comment: Please don't tag multiple irrelevant languages. And please **[edit]** your question if you need to improve it.

Comment: Also please take some time to refresh [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: And in C you [should not cast the result of `malloc`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc/605858). Also build with extra warnings enabled, and treat them as errors (like for example `-Wall -Wextra -Werror`).

Comment: You should add the additional necessary includes to the code shown. These two lines are just a giant memory leak factory: `dirSet->pathSet[loopIndex] = (char *)malloc(TotalFileNameLen); dirSet->pathSet[loopIndex] = dirSet->dirent_ptr->d_name;` You'd get the same result without the leak if you just removed the first line. If you want to allocate space for the name and copy it use `strcpy`. Personally I'd skip the overly large allocation and use `strdup`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem are these assignments:

```
dirSet->pathSet[loopIndex] = (char *)malloc(TotalFileNameLen);
dirSet->pathSet[loopIndex] = dirSet->dirent_ptr->d_name;
```

The first make `dirSet->pathSet[loopIndex]` point to one location. The second make it point somewhere completely different.

Instead of the second assignment you need to *copy the string*:

```
strcpy(dirSet->pathSet[loopIndex], dirSet->dirent_ptr->d_name);
```

---

You're also wasting quite a lot of memory by always allocating a large amount or memory. The likelihood of the string being that large are rather small. Instead use the string length as the base size:

```
dirSet->pathSet[loopIndex] = malloc(strlen(dirSet->dirent_ptr->d_name) + 1);
// +1 for the null terminator
```

Comment: I understand. Thank you for your answer. Sometimes such low-level mistakes are not easy to notice.

Comment: Yes, there is too much memory allocated in my code. I will modify it.